# What cautions shall I take when installing from a deb file without safety guarantee?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, deb

Suppose that I found on a website without well-known reliability a deb file without guarantee that the software it installs does exactly what it is supposed to. So there is possibility that the software it installs can be malicious.

Do I need to (or had better) to  do specifically when installing from the deb file?

Many deb files install software under system directory by default, and when that is the case, can software such installed do more harm than software installed under non system directory if possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> Suppose that I am given a deb file without guarantee that the software it installs does exactly what it is supposed to.

It’s always the case that there is no guarantee that software does exactly what it is supposed to.

The first major risk when installing a package occurs during installation itself: the package can provide maintainer scripts which are run as root, and can do anything they want to the system. You can however examine these before installation:

```
dpkg-deb -R /path/to/package.deb /tmp/extracted
```

then look at the files in `/tmp/extracted/DEBIAN`.

The second major risk occurs every time you run the software. The installation directory has no impact on this, apart from avoiding `PATH`-related issues. The software will have access to anything accessible by the user it runs as: all the readable files, accessible devices (including webcams, microphones etc.), network resources including the Internet, the contents of other windows if it runs under X... All of these can be mitigated to some extent:

- running as another user will limit access to files and devices (assuming your permissions are set appropriately);
- running in a different network namespace will prevent access to network resources;
- running under Wayland rather than X will prevent access to Wayland-driven windows.

The safest approach is to install and run such software in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks. "The safest approach is to install and run such software in a virtual machine." Is it a safe approach to install software from deb files into containers like docker's? Does docker container only work with CLI software not GUI software?

Comment: It’s not as safe as running in a VM. CRI containers can be made to run graphical software, but it’s harder than running CLI or server software; you might want to look at Flatpaks instead.

Answer (score 4):

First, for all debian stuff:

> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
> permitted by applicable law

So basically, this question is relevant for every `.deb` that you install.

There are a number of precautions that you can take:

- download only from a trusted source;
- check your hashes (`apt-get` should so that for you)
- do not install "dodgy" software

Software can do harm when it is executed. It is irrelevant where the file is located, `/usr/bin` or `/opt/...` or even in your home directory. The amount of harm that it can do depends on the uid that executes the software. Root does more harm then a normal user.